# Switch statement with multiple constant-expression in c#. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Cases in Switch:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch)

Is it possible to do a multiple constant-expression switch statement like

```
switch (i) {
   case "run","notrun", "runfaster": //Something like this.
      DoRun();
      break;
   case "save":
      DoSave();
      break;
   default:
      InvalidCommand(command);
      break;
   }
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Yes, it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch). You can use multiple case labels for the same section:

```
switch (i) 
{  
    case "run": 
    case "notrun":
    case "runfaster":   
        DoRun();  
        break;  
    case "save":  
        DoSave();  
        break;  
    default:  
        InvalidCommand(command);  
        break;  
}
```

Comment: I note that you are conceptualizing this as a C-style switch, where there is "fall through" and the gap between the labels can be empty. A better way to think about it in C# is that *each section has one or more labels* and *there is no fall through between sections*.

Comment: @Eric: You are right, that is a much cleaner perspective leaving no room for misinterpretation. The analogy of "fall-through" is a sticky one, a strong visualization, and hard to shake.

Comment: Also, while we're being picky, case labels are "case labels", not "case statements". They are not statements; they are not legal *anywhere* that a statement is legal.