# Multple Criteria in a Single Case inside a Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Hi all I searched and found old answers like in 2008, im creating firefox addon for new browsers so i can use ecma 5+.

I was trying to do a a switch that had one block meet multiple criteria like if >=0 && <= 3 like below:

```
switch (blah) {
     case 0, 1, 2, 3: //<<<<<<<< this here please
          //do this;
          break;
     default:
          ///do this
}
```

This is just a basic example.

I would like multiple values to trigger the same case. How do I do this?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Some questions aren't questions..

Comment: thx qantas, that topic is nice, however it doesnt have the solution provided by Jeronimo, but its good to leave up in the main topic so people can see those approaches as well.

Comment: @Noit: but that's like an if-else statement, just like how I can write `if (x >= 0 && x <= 3) {} else {}`.

Comment: Yeah i just simplified the example very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one hacky switch style that allows you to specify ranges:

```
switch (true) {
    case blah >= 0 && blah <= 3:
        //do this
        break
    default:
        //do that
}
```

It sometimes useful in cases like [this](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/blob/b0fa7ee2d1f9d8b8605c74d01aee10f0d0c3bb7c/lib/logger.js#L6-L14).

Maybe it'll do what you want.

Comment: oh no way!! it works! http://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/x6U5w/
since what version of javascript does this work?

Comment: no idea, I just saw it somewhere and had had an exactly the same reaction :)

Answer (score 9):

This might be what you are looking for. If it is please more clearly define your problem/question.

```
switch (x) {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   // do this
   break;
   default:
   // do this
}
```

See also [Multiple Cases in Switch:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch?rq=1)

Comment: ahhh superb! thanks for the super fast reply!! i cant accept soltuion for 9 minutes lol. this lets me get right back to my program! thx josh!

Comment: hey thx man i selected your solution and jeronimo's below but its not letting me select two solutions

Comment: This really is the better answer. It should have been accepted:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Methods_for_Multi-criteria_Case