# Constant value cannot be converted to a 'bool' using a switch statement C#

Tags: c#, boolean, switch-statement, syntax-error, case-statement

When I try to evaluate the `SelectedIndex` of a `CheckBoxList` and at `bool`. I receive a error on the case in my switch statement in C#. The error is `Constant value '0' cannot be converted to a 'bool'`. Is there a way that I can evaluate both with in a switch statement? I know I can use a if statement, but I would rather use a switch statement if I could.

Here is my code:

```
switch ((CBL_PO.SelectedIndex == 0) && (boolIsNotValid == true))
            {
                case 0: case true:
                    //Do Something
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: There will never be a value `0`.

Comment: What is the need for a switch statement? `(CBL_PO.SelectedIndex == 0) && (boolIsNotValid == true)` can only return true of false

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes there will be a value of 0, someone may check the first box in the list

Comment: I think you are trying to combine two statements in one. You can't.

Comment: @PatrickHofman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch

Comment: That answer states in it's first line: "There is no syntax in C++ nor C# for the second method you mentioned."

Comment: @PatrickHofman Do you not see the answer with 200+ upvotes?

Comment: I do. It has multiple values, but one variable to check against.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58704/discussion-between-nate-and-patrick-hofman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only values in the `switch` can be `true` or `false`, drop the `case 0`.

Alternatively, you could better use an `if`:

```
if (CBL_PO.SelectedIndex == 0 && boolIsNotValid)
{ }
else
{ }
```

Since I think you might be trying to do a check on both values in the `switch`: not possible. This is your best option:

```
switch (CBL_PO.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
    {
        if (boolIsNotValid)
        { }
        else
        { }

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement can be thought of as a replacement for a stack of if/else statements. If you are doing a single comparison then use a simple if statement; switch is overkill.

```
if (CBL_PO.SelectedIndex == 0 && boolIsNotValid)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a switch statement, then you want:

```
switch ((CBL_PO.SelectedIndex == 0) && (boolIsNotValid == true))
    {
        case true:
           //Do Something
           break;
        case false:
           //Do Something else
           break;
    }
```

Comment: So I can evaluate the SelectedIndex == 0 as the case being false? Never thought of that. I am going to try that now.

Comment: I can't change the case to false, if I do, I can't evaluate with checkbox will be checked in the list.