# How to handle multiple values inside one case?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, case-statement

How to handle multiple values inside one `case`? So if I want to execute the same action for value `"first option"` and `"second option"`?

Is this the right way?

```
switch(text)
{
    case "first option":
    {
    }
    case "second option":
    {
        string a="first or Second";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/switch-statement/) article for some guidelines. The main thing that jumps out at me is that the first case is missing a `break` statement

Comment: Friendly suggestion - get used to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: @Max It's wanted, so the following case is executed.

Comment: Thanks @Max the article was helpful. i deliberately escaped a break to cover cases and let execution continue.The brackets after the first case were the root cause of my problem.

Comment: Duplicate of [Multiple Cases in Switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called 'multiple labels' in the documentation, which can be found in the [C# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) on MSDN.

> A switch statement can include any number of switch sections, and each section can have one or more case labels (as shown in the string case labels example below). However, no two case labels may contain the same constant value.

Your altered code:

```
string a = null;

switch(text)
{
    case "first option":
    case "second option":
    {
        a = "first or Second";
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I pulled the `string a` out since else your `a` will only be available inside the `switch`.

Comment: Isn't that quite the same. I thought that case "a": case "b" was just an empty "a" statement that falls though.

Comment: No, in fall through you would have the first block executed. In C# there cannot be a code block for the first option. Btw, I misread, it's not explicitly called "multiple labels".

Comment: @helb: Okay. Got that. Edited the important part of the docs in. Thanks.

Comment: @helb: I noticed too that the name isn't exact, but it will give a hint where to search for.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible

```
switch(i)
                {
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6: 
                        {
                            //do someting
                            break; 
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using just an `if` statement if you want to be able to treat both together and separate as distinct cases:

```
if (first && second)
{
    Console.WriteLine("first and second");
}
else if (first)
{
    Console.WriteLine("first only");
}
else if (second)
{
    Console.WriteLine("second only");
}
```