# C# switch case one line with fallthrough

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Recently as of C# 8.0 they introduced a new switch case that is rapidly replacing our nested ternary if statements in our code base as such:

```
var number = 1;
var evenness = number switch 
{ 
    1 => "odd", 
    2 => "even", 
    3 => "odd", 
    4 => "even",
    _=>"out of range" 
};
```

And I freaking love it! It's really nice, clean and succinct.

However, this could be improved with the following old style switch  statement from this question
[Multiple cases in switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch-statement)

```
string eventness2;
switch (number)
{
    case 1: case 3:
        eventness2 = "odd";
        break;
    case 2: case 4:
        eventness2 = "event";
        break;
    default:
        eventness2 = "out of range";
        break;
}
```

My question is, is there any way to support multiple cases within a one line switch statement similar to this invalid syntax

```
var evenness = number switch { 1,3 => "odd", 2,4 => "even",_=>"out of range";
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course, using pattern matching:

```
var evenness = number switch { 1 or 3 => "odd", 2 or 4 => "even", _ => "out of range" };
```

Comment: Also, stack overflow innappropriately flagged my question as the same as the very question I referenced in the body. How stupid

Comment: @apinostomberry agree that's not helpful; a User must've done that. I think if you' had commented over there asking for the ternary version, you'd be prompted to ask your own question.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. SO is a wonderland