# C# simplify switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement, parameter-passing, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Can I somehow simplify this switch statement as both cases do same thing just with another function parameter?

```
switch (data.Subscriber.Protocol)
{
    case "email json":
        builder.Attachments.Add("Očitanje.json", CraftAttachment(data));
        break;
    case "email text":
        builder.Attachments.Add("Očitanje.txt", CraftAttachment(data));
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple cases in switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch-statement)

Comment: You say "both cases",  but you should really consider `default` to be a separate case. So there are 3. Unless you're saying that "email json" and "email text" are the only possible values, which we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Protocols are read from Db and there are 5 different but I use only 2 of them for email sending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
string attachmentName = data.Subscriber.Protocol switch
{
    "email json" => "Očitanje.json",
    "email text" => "Očitanje.txt",
    _ => null
};

if (attachmentName is not null)
{
    builder.Attachments.Add(attachmentName, CraftAttachment(data));
}
```

[Switch expression | C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression)

Comment: Sometimes when multiple solutions are available I choose the solution most programmers will understand and on that metric your answer wins.

Answer (score 0):

//Another clean approach without using Swtich case:

```
var ProtocolAndFileMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
       {"email json","Očitanje.json"},
       {"email text","Očitanje.json"},
       {"email png","Očitanje.png"},
       {"email Jpeg","Očitanje.Jpeg"}
     };

 builder.Attachments.Add(ProtocolAndFileMappings[data.Subscriber.Protocol], CraftAttachment(data));
```

Comment: This will throw if key is not present. OP code - does not.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using a local function to simplify the call:

```
void add(string s) => if (s != null) builder.Attachments.Add(s, CraftAttachment(data));

add( data.Subscriber.Protocol switch
{
    "email json" => "Očitanje.json",
    "email text" => "Očitanje.txt",
    _ => null
});
```

(Although I think that some folks would criticize that as "too cute...)

NOTE: This solution (like the other solutions) suffers from a drawback.

The code will always make an additional test against null, which the straightforward switch doesn't do - so this is (very marginally) less efficient.

I personally would do it like this (which avoids the drawback):

```
void add(string s) => builder.Attachments.Add(s, CraftAttachment(data));

switch (data.Subscriber.Protocol)
{
    case "email json": add("Očitanje.json"); break;
    case "email text": add("Očitanje.txt")   break;
    default:           /* Do nothing */      break;
}
```

Simple local functions like that are very likely to be inlined by the JIT compiler, so there should be no overhead.